# KNN imputation of numerical variables in pipleine in Dataframe- Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, knn

All,
I'm facing an issue while trying to use KNN imputer in a pipleline. I have listed my workflow as below.

I have separated my Numerical and Categorical Variables and built a pipleline as below

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', KNN(k=3)),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])


categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent', fill_value='missing')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, num_attr),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, cat_attr)])
```

I want to use KNN imputer to impute the missing values in the numerical columns.

I ran logistic regression

```
clf_logreg = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', LogisticRegression())])
clf_logreg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

The above code chunk worked fine but when i'm trying to predict on X_train, i'm getting the below error. Please help me out. Thanks

```
train_pred_logreg = clf_logreg.predict(X_train)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-f17e49913947> in <module>
      1 #train_pred_logreg = clf_logreg.predict(X_train)
----> 2 test_pred_logreg = clf_logreg.predict(X_test)
      3 
      4 print(confusion_matrix(y_true=Y_train, y_pred = train_pred_logreg))
      5 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    114 
    115         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 116         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    117         # update the docstring of the returned function
    118         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    419         Xt = X
    420         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
--> 421             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    422         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    423 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in transform(self, X)
    537                                  'remainder keyword')
    538 
--> 539         Xs = self._fit_transform(X, None, _transform_one, fitted=True)
    540         self._validate_output(Xs)
    541 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted)
    418                     message=self._log_message(name, idx, len(transformers)))
    419                 for idx, (name, trans, column, weight) in enumerate(
--> 420                         self._iter(fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True), 1))
    421         except ValueError as e:
    422             if "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" in str(e):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    919             # remaining jobs.
    920             self._iterating = False
--> 921             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    922                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
    923 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    757                 return False
    758             else:
--> 759                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    760                 return True
    761 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    714         with self._lock:
    715             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 716             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    717             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    718             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    180     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    181         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 182         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    183         if callback:
    184             callback(result)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    547         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    548         # arguments in memory
--> 549         self.results = batch()
    550 
    551     def get(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params)
    693 
    694 def _transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params):
--> 695     res = transformer.transform(X)
    696     # if we have a weight for this transformer, multiply output
    697     if weight is None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _transform(self, X)
    538         Xt = X
    539         for _, _, transform in self._iter():
--> 540             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    541         return Xt
    542 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fancyimpute/solver.py in transform(self, X, y)
    223             "doesn't support inductive mode. Only %s.fit_transform is "
    224             "supported at this time." % (
--> 225                 self.__class__.__name__, self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: KNN.transform not implemented! This imputation algorithm likely doesn't support inductive mode. Only KNN.fit_transform is supported at this time.
```

When I try to use fit_transform as shown in the error message I get the below error

```
clf_logreg.fit_transform(X_train, Y_train)

AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `clf_logreg.preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train, Y_train)` to test if KNN works. As per the logistic regression, it doesn't have a transform method as it's a classification method.

Comment: doesn't work. I get below error
AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'preprocessor'

Comment: Sorry, how about ```clf_logreg['preprocessor'].fit_transform(X_train, Y_train)```?

Comment: :( I'll tell you if I try it on my own and find a solution. Good luck!